# How could i make rotating tiles animation like in this video

Tags: animation, particles, transforms, constraints, effects

So i've been triyng to replicate something that you can see [in this new game of thrones intro](https://youtu.be/TZE9gVF1QbA?t=10) starting at the 10 second mark, where the ground is made of these slabs/tiles and they rotate in this sort of nice wavy form.

[image]

I tried to play around with with different stuff in blender, but haven't been able to replicate this effect when there is hundreds of tiles.

Of course i could just animate each tile individually, but that would take ages.

Comment: Could you please explain a little better with words the effect you are trying to achieve, perhaps post an image or two, so your question doesn't rely exclusively on watching a video?

Comment: I agree with Duarte. The answer is most likely going to be Animation Nodes, though. Rotating tiles is what 80% of the tutorials using them demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could select all the tiles that are meant to rotated and animate them all together, then offset the animations in the Graph Editor, after selecting all tiles except the first, by sliding (G, X) the start and end keys to the right, then deselect the second tile, and slide the rest of the keys to the right again, deselect the third tile, slide the keys along and so on. Still quite a bit of work, but not as bad as doing everything for each one individually.